# Man dreams of an alien invasion of Earth and it comes true

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a Sci-fi movie that aired on PBS in the mid-seventies. I'm guessing at the circa.  But I think that was about the time because I had a lot of stuff falling on my head, so remembering a movie title was probably low on my list.

I remember a man dreamed a dream, then it came true the next day.  The only specific dream I remember was the Earth was invaded by aliens.  Bingo, the next day it happened.  I remember the aliens were roundish and cyborg-ish.

I remember I think I liked it.  I have been asking for 40 years.  I found one other person who remembered the movie, but that was all they remembered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be [The Lathe of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven_%28film%29). PBS were the distributors for this movie. [IMDb link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081036/)

Plot:

> Orr's explanation of his drug abuse is incredible: he has known since age 17 that his dreams change reality, and tries to prevent himself from dreaming because he fears their effects.
>
> ...
>
> > Haber suggests that Orr dream of a solution to overpopulation (resulting in a plague wiping out three-fourths of the human population), the end to all conflict between people (**resulting in an alien invasion uniting mankind**), only after numerous failed attempts to "make the world right" admitting to Orr that he believes in Orr's power.